# How to align DIVs in center

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to make 3 divs equidistant from each other and also want to align then in center. I am using Foundation framework to make it responsive.It should be

[image]

**css:**

```
 *, *:before, *:after {
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 *, *:before, *:after {
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 .large-10 {
   width: 83.3333%;
  }
 .column, .columns {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 0.9375em;
    padding-right: 0.9375em;
    position: relative;
 }
 div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, p, blockquote, th, td   {
     margin: 0;
 }
 *, *:before, *:after {
     box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 body {
     color: #222222;
     cursor: default;
     font-family: "Helvetica Neue","Helvetica",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
     font-style: normal;
     font-weight: normal;
     line-height: 1;
 }
  html, body {
     font-size: 100%;
  }
```

and [this](http://ec2-54-178-189-98.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/SamePage_Website/SamePage_web_performance_japan_2.html) is the website url.

Foundation class 
        
makes it forcefully align left. I am not able to align it center.

```
<center>   
      <div class="large-10 columns">
         <div class="large-3 columns webImageText">
            <div class="large-12 columns subWebImageText">イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績</div>
            <div class="large-12 columns subWebImageText2">イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績</div>
               <div class="large-12 columns"><img id="imageStyle" src="img/image48.JPG"></div>
          </div>  
          <div class="large-3 columns webImageText" style="float:left;">
               <div class="large-12 columns subWebImageText" style="font-weight:none;">イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績</div>
               <div class="large-12 columns subWebImageText2">イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績</div>
               <div class="large-12 columns"><img id="imageStyle" src="img/image49.JPG"></div>
          </div> 
          <div class="large-3 columns webImageText" style="float:left;overflow:hidden;margin-right:0;">
               <div class="large-12 columns subWebImageText">イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績</div>
               <div class="large-12 columns subWebImageText2">イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績</div>
               <div class="large-12 columns"><img id="imageStyle" src="img/image50.JPG"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </center>
```

Need ur help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Foundation Zurb you can use the *.<small/large>-centered* classes, e.g.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="columns small-10 small-centered">
        <!-- your content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The [documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html#centered-columns) has more information about the grid.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <center>   
      <div class="large-10 columns">
         <div class="large-3 columns webImageText">
            <div class="large-12 columns subWebImageText">イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績</div>
            <div class="large-12 columns subWebImageText2">イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績</div>
               <div class="large-12 columns"><img id="imageStyle" src="img/image48.JPG"></div>
          </div>  
          <div class="large-3 columns webImageText" >
               <div class="large-12 columns subWebImageText" style="font-weight:none;">イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績</div>
               <div class="large-12 columns subWebImageText2">イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績</div>
               <div class="large-12 columns"><img id="imageStyle" src="img/image49.JPG"></div>
          </div> 
          <div class="large-3 columns webImageText">
               <div class="large-12 columns subWebImageText">イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績</div>
               <div class="large-12 columns subWebImageText2">イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績イト実績</div>
               <div class="large-12 columns"><img id="imageStyle" src="img/image50.JPG"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </center>
```

This should align the div to come in center the mistake done  you have added float left as inline in last two div that causes the issues I have removed the both inline css in your div  that provide the solution you want. Check it let me know for any queries

Comment: http://ec2-54-178-189-98.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/SamePage_Website/img/afterTest.JPG
result is like this.

Comment: ok you want to make the image equal distance from the three div or what type of center you want?

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col"></div>
     <div class="col"></div>
     <div class="col"></div>
 </div>
```

CSS :

```
.container{ text-align:center }
.col{ display:inline-block; min-height:200px; }
```

Comment: i have to overwrite the css of foundation here. U can check from the website link i have given.

Comment: Just change the css selectors i.e .col to .webImageText. Try using !important to overwrite the existing css.
.webImageText{ display:inline-block; float:none !important; }

Answer (score 0):

To align all the three elements in the center target the column element they are within like this:

```
div.large-10.columns {220px auto;}
```

or something like this

```
div.large-10.columns{
margin-top:0;
margin-right:auto;
margin-bottom:0;
margin-left:220px; }
```

change 220px with the desired value to align them with your desired configuration or you can also try the margin{0 auto} feature.
[image: This is what it will look like]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
margin:0px auto;
```

in body tag